# trying to format a jquery date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've got this jquery date field - where the users enters their DOB (date of birth) called 'startDob'.

I'm adding 66years on to this value to show a retirement date ('retDate'), which looks like this:

```
var retDate = new Date(startDob.getFullYear() + 66, startDob.getMonth(), startDob.getDate());
```

the result looks unsavoury:

```
Wed Feb 08 2073 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

I've tried formatting like this:

```
 $('#dateEnd').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'}); 
 $('#retDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});
```

to no avail.
when this box was an actual datepicker calendar box, I could format like so:

> dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",

but now I cannot format it at all. Any ideas please?

[here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z18ct2xe/2/)

Comment: You are using jquery ui. Why not use `$.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy',retDate)`?

Comment: I gave up on the jquery datepicker and used the html5 one instead: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

Comment: hi, just tried: 
`code $.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy',retDate); ` 
as suggested, but this had no effect.

Comment: this is now sorted. I used:   `code retDateStr = retDate.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");  `